# Can I run Synergy Client on Windows without installing it?

Tags: synergy

I have a machine to which I do not have Administrator rights.  I tried building Synergy and putting together a folder with EXE's and DLL's, but it complains that the connection is refused (on the client) and won't connect to the server.  Is there a way to create a run folder, so that we can avoid needing to run Windows Installer?

The error log in the window (without even clicking Start to connect the client) is:

```
NOTE:  connecting to service...
ERROR: ipc connection error, connection refused
```

I assume it is trying to connect to synergyd.exe as a Windows service?  Of course I don't have permissions to create/start a service.

Comment: If you don't have permissions, seek them from the powers that can give them to you.  If they won't, then you pretty much have to live with it, as it's not your computer. :)  Regardless of that, I'm not sure what you are asking from us exactly...  We can't get you admin permissions, and you need them to install a service.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to run without admin rights, without the need to install a service.  That would be downright convenient, especially for systems where we have no control over what software gets approved for installation.

Comment: Bolton released a portable version about a year ago but he took it down and there hasn't been any word since.  I constantly run into this wall when working with client laptops.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the client to connect by copying the files from the synergy install directory from the server to the client and running synergyc from the client's command prompt.

Comment: This works just fine, just running `synergyc.exe theServersName` from `cmd`, Windows 10, no admin privileges required

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no portable version any more (thanks phil for answering).

Comment: Deleted my post because Donald Duck was right - they removed the thread with the instructions that I was linking to

Comment: @RobHerms is right. I was able to run client just by copying binaries.

Comment: Only the command-line client (I have 1.9.1) works, the GUI client doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

This expands on @RobHerms answer with step-by-step instructions. This worked just fine for me on a limited account.

1. [Download](https://symless.com/synergy/download) the Synergy MSI installer
2. Run this from windows command line to extract the files: `msiexec /a PathToMSIfile /qb TARGETDIR=PathToTargetFolder`
3. You'll find synergyc.exe in your target folder path.
4. If you want to enable SSL, you need to put a TrustedServers.txt file with the server fingerprint in this path: `C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Synergy\SSL\Fingerprints\TrustedServers.txt`
5. Create a shortcut to synergyc.exe with the appropriate flags. Mine looks like this: `"C:\Users\USER_NAME\PortableApps\SynergyPortable\synergyc.exe" -1 --enable-crypto --name PreSetClientName x.x.x.x`

Answer (score -1):

You can register synergyd.exe with the Windows service framework with the following steps

1. Open an admin command prompt (elevated)
2. Navigate to the directory your synergy executables are in
3. Run: synergyd.exe /install

If you fire up the Services snap in (or just run services.msc from the command line) you should notice it is now registered and running.

After that, restart your clients and you should be good to go :)

Comment: Doesn't this installs Synergy?

Comment: Like the question says, Admin access to the OS is not available, so that is not a viable answer.  A portable version would have worked, but alas, that is no longer available.